# Files "disappearing" from initramfs

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, embedded-linux

On an embedded platform running Linux 2.6.36, I occasionally run into a problem where files do not appear in the root file system that *ARE* present in our initramfs cpio file.

I am building the initramfs from a cpio listing file (see `gen_init_cpio.c`), but also ran into the problem before when just using a full directory.

When I say I know the files are present in the cpio file, I mean if I extract `usr/initrmafs_data.cpio.gz` the files are there.

It seems to be loosely related to the amount of content in the initramfs, but I haven't found the magic number of files and/or total storage size that causes files to start disappearing.

Is there an option in `make menuconfig` I'm missing that would fix this?  A boot argument?  Something else?

Any suggestions?

**Update**:  To clarify, this is with a built-in ramdisk using `CONFIG_INITRAMFS_SOURCE` and it's compressed with gzip via setting `CONFIG_INITRAMFS_COMPRESSION_GZIP`.  Also, this is for a `mipsel-linux` platform.

**Update #2**:  I've added a printk to `init/initramfs.c:clean_path` and mysteriously, the previously "disappearing" files are now all there.  I think this sorta seems to point to a kernel bug if attempting to log the behavior altered the behavior.  I'll compare initramfs.c against a newer kernel tomorrow to see if that sheds any light on the matter.

Comment: Vote-to-close people:  Since when does issues involving *compiling* the kernel go on superuser.com?  I'm currently adding `printk` statements and hacking up "init/*.c" files to get to the bottom of this.....

Comment: This is the kind of integration issue that's on-topic but borderline here, is utterly offside for [su], borderline on [unix.se], and would probably do best on [its own site](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/70800/embedded-systems?referrer=ugotaNldoh5JOVkcEm-iDw2).

Answer (score 0):

Probably your image size is bigger than default ramdisk size (4MB afaik). Check if adding `ramdisk_size=valuebiggerthanyourimagesize` as a kernel parameter (before `root=...` parameter) solves your problem. You can also try to change kernel config value `CONFIG_BLK_DEV_RAM_SIZE`.

Comment: Good suggestion, but no luck with either. :(.  CONFIG_BLK_DEV_RAM_SIZE is already *significantly* larger than the initramfs image post-decompression.

Comment: Well, looks I confused old-style initrd with initramfs, so this parameter really shouldn't matter. Do the files also disappear if you do not built initramfs into the kernel, but load it as initrd (if your bootloader could do that ofc)?